# In SwiftUI how do I animate changes one at a time when they occur in a called method?

Tags: animation, swiftui

Although I get an animation when I tap the button, it's not the animation I want.
The entire view is being replaced at once, but I want to see each element change in sequence. I tried in both the parent view and in the called method. Neither produces the desired result.

(this is a simplified version of the original code)

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SequencedCell: Identifiable {
   let id = UUID()
   var value: Int

   mutating func addOne() {
      value += 1
   }

}

struct AQTwo: View {
   @State var cells: [SequencedCell]

   init() {
      _cells = State(initialValue: (0 ..< 12).map { SequencedCell(value: $0) })
   }

   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         Spacer()
         Button("+") {
            sequencingMethod(items: $cells)
         }
         .font(.largeTitle)
         Spacer()

         HStack {
            ForEach(Array(cells.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, item in
 //              withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4)) {
               Text("\(item.value)").tag(index)
 //              }
            }
         }
         Spacer()
      }
   }

   func sequencingMethod(items: Binding<[SequencedCell]>) {
      for cell in items {
         withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4)) {
            cell.wrappedValue = SequencedCell(value: cell.wrappedValue.value + 1)
           // cell.wrappedValue.addOne()
        }
      }
   }
}


struct AQTwoPreview: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
      AQTwo()
   }
}
```

So I want the 0 to turn into a 1, the 1 then turn into a 2, etc.

[image: Screencast]

Edit:
**Even though I have accepted an answer, it answered my question, but didn't solve my issue.**

I can't use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` because the value I am updating is an inout parameter and it makes the compiler unhappy:

```
Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter 'grid'
```

So I tried Malcolm's (malhal) suggestion to use delay, but everything happens immediately with no sequential animation (the entire block of updated items animate as one)

Here's the recursive method I am calling:

```swift
   static func recursiveAlgorithm(targetFill fillValue: Int, in grid: inout [[CellItem]],
                                  at point: (x: Int, y: Int), originalFill: Int? = nil,  delay: TimeInterval) -> [[CellItem]] {
      /// make sure the point is on the board (or return)
      guard isValidPlacement(point) else { return grid }
      /// the first time this is called we don't have `originalFill`
      /// so we read it from the starting point
      let tick = delay + 0.2
      //AnimationTimer.shared.tick()
      let startValue = originalFill ?? grid[point.x][point.y].value
      if grid[point.x][point.y].value == startValue {
         withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.1).delay(tick)) {
            grid[point.x][point.y].value = fillValue
                  }
         _ = recursiveAlgorithm(targetFill: fillValue, in: &grid, at: (point.x, point.y - 1), originalFill: startValue, delay: tick)
         _ = recursiveAlgorithm(targetFill: fillValue, in: &grid, at: (point.x, point.y + 1), originalFill: startValue, delay: tick)
         _ = recursiveAlgorithm(targetFill: fillValue, in: &grid, at: (point.x - 1, point.y), originalFill: startValue, delay: tick)
         _ = recursiveAlgorithm(targetFill: fillValue, in: &grid, at: (point.x + 1, point.y), originalFill: startValue, delay: tick)
      }
      return grid
   }
```

Further comments/suggestions are welcome, as I continue to wrestle with this.

Comment: You would have to wait in between you calls to increment the values. The lowest-tech way to do this is probably to add a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` inside your loop and make sure that the time it waits is increased each time.

Comment: the actual code is running inside a recursive function that's modifying an inout variable, so I'm not having an easy time getting it to work. If you want to write something up I'll be happy to accept it and meanwhile I'll keep futzing with your approach. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the lowest-tech version is probably just using a `DisatpchQueue.main.asyncAfter` call:

```
func sequencingMethod(items: Binding<[SequencedCell]>) {
    var wait: TimeInterval = 0.0
    
    for cell in items {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + wait) {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
                cell.wrappedValue = SequencedCell(value: cell.wrappedValue.value + 1)
            }
        }
        wait += 1.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [delay(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/animation/delay(_:)) for that, e.g.

```
func sequencingMethod(items: Binding<[SequencedCell]>) {
       var delayDuration = 0.0
       for cell in items {
           withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4).delay(delayDuration)) {
              cell.wrappedValue = SequencedCell(value: cell.wrappedValue.value + 1)
        }
        delayDuration += 0.5
      }
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding! In the simplified case I presented this does indeed work. However, I am updating from within a recursive function, and I'm not observing any delay. I'll update my question with the method and comments.

Comment: you need to pass the delay duration into the recursive function and increment it

Comment: OK. I just tried that, but am getting the same results. I updated my example to show what I have so far.

Comment: I got it to work by using your approach and using a non-recursive algorithm instead. Many thanks and upvoted!